# adding a div only if number of charecter exceeds the set limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a div to pdpTab5 if the tab contains more than 540 charecters. Where i will be creating a "read more..." sort of situation through a modal.

I am truncating the text by using this. But the part of adding a div is making me confused. I dont want to show the div if the tab contains less than 540 charecters.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var myDiv = $('#pdpTab5');
        myDiv.html(myDiv.html().substring(0,540));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to create the additional div inside `myDiv`?

Comment: If you search for "jquery ellipsis" I think you can find some plugins to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
      var myDiv = $('#pdpTab5'),
          divChars = myDiv.text(),
          shortened = divChars.substring(0, 540) + "... <a href='#' class='readMore'>Read more</a>",
          $new =$(myDiv.clone().html(shortened));


      if (divChars.length > 540) {
          // Perform some action here, not quite sure what you wanted to do 
          myDiv.empty().append($new).find(".readMore").on("click", function() {

              $(this).parent().empty().text(divChars);
          });


      }
 });
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JRk34/)

Comment: BThis is the closest I think. But maybe I am missing something. I am not able to see the read more. Any ideas

Comment: Do you mean, after clicking the link?

Comment: hey there. I am not seeing the link. That is the problem. Also it is not truncating the text. But I think I have found a work around this. I think I am going to show the read more for all cases and hide when the number of charecters is< 540. I think that would be easier and logical

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var myDiv = $('#pdpTab5');


        if(myDiv.html().length > 540){
            // create new div
            myDiv.parent().append("<div>" + myDiv.html().substring(540) + "</div>");
        }
        myDiv.html(myDiv.html().substring(0,540));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately none it actually worked. I tried all of these. :-(